# Visual C++ can't find libraries - depending on library folder order

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual C++ project that uses both CUDA and Boost. I have the following environment variables pointing to different libraries:

```
BOOST64_Lib = c:\boost\1_57_0\lib64-msvc-11.0
CUDA_LIB_PATH = c:\program files (x86)\NVidia\GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\lib\x64
```

My VC++ Directories setting includes the following libraries:

```
$(BOOST64_Lib);$(CUDA_LIB_PATH);$(LibraryPath)
```

When I compile the project, I get an error saying `cudart.lib` can't be found. If I move $(CUDA_LIB_PATH) to the beginning of the VC++ Library directories, I get an error saying `msvcprtd.lib` cannot be found.

`msvcprtd.lib` exists in the proper place (VC\lib\amd64 under Visual Studio 2012). `cudart.lib` obviously exists in the CUDA library folder.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and the specific project is compiled with the Visual Studio 2012 (v110) Platform Toolset.

I must be missing something *really* small, that makes the linker complain about different libraries based on the order of library folders, but I can't find what that is.

Comment: I think you can move Librarypath at begining.

Comment: Try to put directory names into the libpath explicitly, without using env variables. Cuda path may need quotes because it is using spaces.

Comment: The build log doesn't contain any clues, it just lists the obj files and a couple of lib files, and then concludes with 'cannot open file msvcprtd.lib'...

Answer (score 1):

Either set

```
CUDA_LIB_PATH = "c:\program files (x86)\NVidia\GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\lib\x64"
```

or

```
LibraryPath = $(BOOST64_Lib);'$(CUDA_LIB_PATH)';$(LibraryPath)
```

To get informative build log set `Tools / Options / Projects And Solutions / Build and Run/MSBuild output verbosity` to Normal.